# Auto Submit Form After X Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with a single input that is being filled by a barcode scanner. I am trying to use JS or Jquery to submit the form only if the contents of the input are 7 characters. I would like it the form to AUTO submit, without the user having to click submit. I have looked at many examples, but have yet to find a working solution.

here is my attempt:

```
<form action="PupListMobile.php" id="my_form" method="get">
     <label for="text-1"></label>
     <input type="text" autofocus name="sID" id="sID" value="" id="my_button" placeholder="CLICK TO SCAN:">
     <input type="hidden" name="lane" value="1" />
     <input id="subHere"type="submit" value="Submit"  />

</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#sID').keyup(function(){
    if(this.value.length ==7){
    $('#subHere').click();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with the following:

1. Add `maxlength="7"` to the text input since you are using `keyup(..)` so that you can't hold a key down to force the text input longer than 7 characters
2. Use a jquery function to detect the length and then submit the form of the input

**Setting the max length**

```
<input type="text" autofocus name="sID" id="sID" value=""
    id="my_button" placeholder="CLICK TO SCAN:" maxlength="7" />
```

**Auto-submit the form**

```js
    $(function() {
      var $id = $('#sID');
      $id.keyup(function(e) {
        if ($id.val().length >= 7) {
          $(this.form).submit();
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="PupListMobile.php" id="my_form" method="get">
     <label for="text-1"></label>
     <input type="text" autofocus name="sID" id="sID" value="" id="my_button" placeholder="CLICK TO SCAN:" maxlength="7" />
     <input type="hidden" name="lane" value="1" />
     <input id="subHere"type="submit" value="Submit"  />

</form>
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I've spent hours looking for fixes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#sID').keyup(function(){
       if(this.value.length ==7){
          alert(123);
         $('#subHere').click();
       }
    }); 
})
```

you can test this